# JavaScript Timer countdown to logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timeout

I'm trying to make a countdown timer in JS that will change the value of a field every one minute (in the begining there is 20, and then change it to 19,18,17 etc), but it's not working correctly. It's changing value not every 60sec but I have a feel that it works random (sometimes it change value first time after 15 sec, another time it's 53). Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
function getTimeNow(){
    var Time = new Date;
    return Time.getHours()*60*60+Time.getMinutes()*60 + Time.getSeconds();
}

    var start = getTimeNow();
    var start_point = start%60;
    var target = start+60*20;


function TimeOut(){
    if((getTimeNow()-start)%60 == start_point && target>getTimeNow()){
       var temp = jQuery('.Timer').html();
       temp-=1;
       jQuery('.Timer').html(temp);
    }
    setTimeout(TimeOut,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot count on the exact moment a timer function will be called. You need to change your logic to something more resilient to time shifts...

```
setInterval(function(){count.innerText = count.innerText - 1;},
            60*1000);
```

this is also a lot shorter...

Comment: OMG, I didn't even think about using intervals, I thought that only reasonable way to do it is to use realtime that I get from Date module... Well that changes evrything...